# Почему после вызова функции DestroyWindow не вызывается функция MessageBox

Tags: c++, winapi

Я использую код

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

LRESULT WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    if (message == WM_DESTROY)
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
    else if (message == WM_PAINT)
    {
        Sleep(2000)
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
    else 
    {
        return DefWindowProcA(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam);
    }
}

int main()
{
    WNDCLASSA wndcls;
    memset(&wndcls, 0, sizeof(wndcls));
    wndcls.lpszClassName = "CLASS";
    wndcls.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    RegisterClassA(&wndcls);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(wndcls.lszClassName,
         NULL,
         WS_OVERLAPPENDWINDOW,
         10,
         10,
         500,
         200,
         NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0))
    {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    Sleep(2000)
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Text", "Header", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return 0;
}
```

Выводится окно созданное через `hwnd` затем закрывается через функцию `DestroyWindow(hwnd)`, но окно созданное через `MessageBoxA` не выводится, далее просто завершается программа. Если я убираю `PostQuitMessage(0)` из условия `WM_PAINT`, то `MessageBox` срабатывает как надо. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Функция `WndProc` содержит неопределенное поведение, так как не все пути возвращают значение. Кроме того, эта функция не соответствует сигнатуре для функции обратного вызова для окна, и в коде есть ошибки синтаксиса. Так что он даже не собирается.

Comment: [Здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postquitmessage) можно почитать про `PostQuitMessage`. Если кратко - это сигнал приложению о том, что нужно завершить работу.

Comment: Не похоже на дословный код -- у `GetMessage` больше параметров

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутри `MessageBox` есть цикл сообщений, который тоже завершается по `WM_QUIT`. Лишние `WM_QUIT` из первого цикла завершают и второй цикл.

Это штатный способ выхода из вложенных циклов сообщений; правильно достигать этого эффекта так:

```
    while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    PostQuitMessage(msg.wParam); // передали предыдущий параметр PostQuitMessage дальше
```